# Why the arccos of adjacent leg is not equal to arcsin to the oposit leg for the right triangle

Tags: geometry, rectangles

Silly question. I have a right triangle with  adjacent leg $A = 81.67$ and an opposite leg $B = -1225.53$. So hypotenuse $C$ will be $\sqrt{(A^2 + B^2)} = 1228.25$.

$\arccos(A / C) = 1.50$ and $\arcsin(B / C) = 3.07$. Why are they not the same, what is the reason of difference?
( I have used python for calculations)

P.S.
Negative size means that leg goes from origin to the negative X direction

Comment: Why did folks approve the edit that removed the negative sign from leg $B$?

Comment: I have added minus again. Maybe that is reason of difference.. My rectangle goes to the nagative coordinate

Comment: No...even with the minus sign, all that happens is that the sign of the arcsin changes. Go ahead and show us your Python code (if it's short). (To paste it in, click on the `{}` button, and it'll end up looking like code rather than a mess.)

Answer (score 1):

You did your computation wrong; the arcsin of $1225.53/1228.25$ is approximately $1.504$ radians.

The arcsin will never produce a value outside the range $-\pi/2 \le u \le \pi/2$, which is approximately $-1.57 \le u \le 1.57$.

(The original question had a negative-sign before the $1225.53$; in that case, the arcsin is $-1.504$ radians, again, not the same as $3.07$.)

Comment: Thanks. I have used python for the calculations.. I wiil investivate the reason of this mistake